# x-editable, how to process the after the field has been posted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, x-editable

editable for my application project. I am very new to AJAX and Jquery. I have read the X-editable documentation but did not quite understand it. My question is how to process the edited field that has been `POST`ed to a url. I did create a `post.php` page to process but it is not catching the value submitted.

My jquery code

```
 $('#username').editable({
    type:'text',
    pk:'1',
    url:'post.php',//Is this where I should define my processing url??
    title:'Enter example'
});
```

and my html form that the inline edit occurs

```
 <div>
    <span>Username:</span>
    <a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-name="username" data-placement="right" data-title="Enter username">superuser</a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span>Status:</span>
    <a href="#" id="status"></a>
  </div>
```

and my php.post process code.(this is not catching the `POST` data).

```
<?php
$value= $_POST['value'];
echo $value;
?>
```

X-editable [Demo Page](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html)
X-editable documentation can be found [here](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#backend).
Thank you so much. I hope you understand the question.

Comment: I suppose you need `data-name="value"` or in POST use `$_POST['username'];`

Comment: And what are the headers the browser sends? You can look at them by F12 in Chrome and choosing Network.

Comment: In you case it should post the following values. name:username value:<value entered> pk:1. try putting logs in php if the request is coming at all, and also use browser dev tool to see what data it is posting.

Comment: to open browser dev tools on chrome you can do F12, go to network tab, and try to submit the data see if it shows any entry.

Comment: Thank you, the script is now posted and the header shows the green 200 OK and the form data sent contains name value and PK so, I guess its working for now. Thank you so much.